# Rails app running on passenger appears to freeze on process startup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, bower, browserify, sprockets

I have a Rails app that is using the Gemfile attached to this post. When I a try to deploy the app on production using passenger and apache, on the first visit to the website, the browser keeps loading forever and no error is thrown at the page or at the browser.

On development and staging environments the problem seems not to appear.

I am using browserify and bower on this particular Gemfile, but have also configured the app to only use bower for trying to make it easier to debug the problem, but up to now, no luck so far.

Any idea of what could be wrong or on how to debug better the **assets pipeline** and/or **passenger**?

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'ckeditor_rails'

gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'curb'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.3'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

gem 'em-synchrony'

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails   /jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

gem 'addressable'

gem 'rack-rewrite'
gem 'stringex'
gem 'geokit-rails'

gem 'sitemap_generator'
gem 'whenever', :require => false

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

group :assets do
  gem 'less-rails', '~> 2.7.0'
  gem 'therubyracer'
end

gem 'ruby-continent'

# DB gems
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.18'

gem 'browser'

gem 'devise'
gem 'zip-zip'
gem 'iconv'

gem 'react-rails', '~> 1.5.0'
gem 'browserify-rails', '~>0.5'

# Development gems
group :development do
  gem 'derailed'
  gem 'colorize'
  gem 'net-ssh'
  gem 'capistrano'
  gem 'capistrano-bundler', '~> 1.1.2'
  gem "capistrano-rvm", '0.1.2'
  gem "capistrano-rbenv", '2.0.3', require: false
  gem 'capistrano-bower'
  #gem 'capistrano-passenger'
  gem 'spork'
  gem 'email_spec'
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0'
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.2.0'
  # https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks
  gem 'rspec-mocks'
  # https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.25.0'
  gem 'factory_girl'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'poltergeist'
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end
```